# heroku/rails/chrome/selenium: error while loading shared libraries: libxshmfence.so.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

Running Capybara using Selenium and Chrome on RoR on Heroku. It all worked well until yesterday when I updated to Chrome v88.

I am getting the following error:

```
/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libxshmfence.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Heroku stack 20. Haven't been able to find anyone with a similar issue so far.

How to figure out if it's a chrome issue? a chromedriver issue? a heroku issue? any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the chrome buildpack page:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/issues/105

1 Add the buildpack:

"https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt"

2 Add a file called Aptfile at the root of your app

3 paste libxshmfence-dev in the file